# In perfect forwarding what is the difference between `decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...` and Args&&

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, std-function, perfect-forwarding

Today I was learning about perfect forwarding, and I created this code sample

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

    template<typename Function, typename... Args>
    auto toStdFun(Function&& fun, Args&&...args)
    {
        using retType = decltype(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

        return std::function<retType(decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...)>(fun);

    }

    int main()
    {
        toStdFun([] () {});

    }
```

Then, someone told me using `decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...` could be represented simply by `Args&&...` like so:

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

    template<typename Function, typename... Args>
    auto toStdFun(Function&& fun, Args&&...args)
    {
        using retType = decltype(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

        return std::function<retType(Args&&...)>(fun);

    }

    int main()
    {
        toStdFun([] () {});

    }
```

What is the difference between the two samples?

Comment: I'd say none: if the type is an rvalue reference, [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) applied to an xvalue is an rvalue reference type, and a [function call return an rvalue reference is an xvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category); if the type is a lvalue reference, then `std::forward` returns a lvalue reference instead and decltype also is an lvalue reference type. (take this with a grain of salt, I might have omitted something, that would not be my first stupid comment today)

Comment: Hehe was that on my other question (the code is almost identical but the question is completely different)?

Comment: What does `std::is_same<>` give you when you compare those types?

Comment: Limited to a single argument; http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3645a1e3ab2cfba4, so yes, looks like they are the same thing.

Comment: If you don't limit it to "perfect forwarding" but to the two expressions in general, the two may differ, but only if function references are involved and you (which isn't really anymore perfect forwarding) call the "forwarding" function with `f<FunctionType>(functionName)`.

Comment: @johannes schaub true true

Comment: That code is awful: dedcing forwarding types and throwing out values then using thoae forwarded types in an unrelated context?  Ick.

Comment: @Yakk what do you mean? I know this code isn't actually useful. It's just a minimal test case as per the stack overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::forward<T>` does nothing more than add `&&` to type `T` and apply reference collapsing rules, when used to forward arguments. So does `Args&&...`

So IMHO, `decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...` and `Args&&...` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use another syntax.
Your code would require argument types as VALUES in form comma-separated list after the lambda for your toStdFun

```
toStdFun([](int a, float b){}, float{}, int{} );
```

If the arguments are not floats but classes/composite types, you sacrifice performance by constructing the instances - just to be wasted.
Also the syntax RetType(Args...) is more natural and resembles the `std::function<int(float,float)>` 
style

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// For generic types that are functors, delegate to its 'operator()'

template <typename T>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

// for pointers to member function
template <typename ClassType, typename RetType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<RetType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using signature_type = RetType (Args...); // strip the lambda class and use only operator signature
};

template <typename T>
auto make_function(T && t)
{
    using signature = typename function_traits<T>::signature_type;
    return std::function<signature>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main()
{
    struct Typ {
        Typ(int a) {
            std::cout << "--CTOR--";
        }
    };
    auto f = make_function([] (Typ t) {
    });
    std::cout << "BEFORE CTOR";
    f(1); // perfect forwarding Ctor is called only once
    std::cout << "AFTER CTOR";
}
```